# 500 : Internal Server Error in Jupyter notebook

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, jupyter

I am trying to access **.ipynb** file in my **Windows C** drive using Ubuntu installed via **WSL2**. I have installed a **conda environment** in Ubuntu where I have installed packages like **Tensorflow.**. (Tensorflow is not installed in Windows).

It shows 500 : Internal Server Error when I open a ipynb file.

Can someone tell me what the problem is?